# Django login using email

Tags: django

I want to login on website, using user's email.

I have:
models.py

```
class User(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField()
    password = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    client_id = models.IntegerField()
    role = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

So, as far as I understand it will be hard to create Customer User model, after migrations to db.

Can I just use this code to login, or I need to change user's model?

P.s. It's not standart login user's model, can I logout using standart auth.logout?

urls:

```
url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
url(r'^main/$', MainPage, name="main"),
url(r'^login/$', UserLogin, name="login"),

url(r'^$', HomeView, name="home"),
url(r'^logout/$', Logout, name="logout"),
```

views.py

```
def UserLogin(request):
    email = request.POST.get('email',False)
    password =  request.POST.get('password',False)
    user = authenticate(email=email,password=password)
    if user is not None:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('Main.html')
    else:
       return HttpResponseRedirect('Index.html')

def Logout(request):
    auth.logout(request)
    return render_to_response('Login.html')
```

Html code:

```
 <form class="m-t" role="form" action="/login" method="post">

     <div class="form-group">
         <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Username"  required="">
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
          <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required="">
     </div>
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary block full-width m-b">Login</button>

     <a href="password.html">
         <small>Forgot password?</small>
     </a>
     <a class="btn btn-sm btn-white btn-block" href="reg.html">Create an account</a>
 </form>
```

After running server with url .8000/login, every try program returns user = None, and redirects to Index.html.

I thought, that I have this mistake because I'm already logged in, but now I'm not sure. Also, When I try to logout from Main.html page, using action = "/logout" it retuns (Page not found).

Comment: Don't use a custom `User` model like this - the password is not encrypted. The [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model) explain how to use a custom model correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Django provide a authentication system by default, this manage everything related with this, it includes an authentication function to create login cookies, provide hashing password and more. My advice is use the actual, if you need to modify something there are many ways to extend it. I leave you a [complete tutorial to do that](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/22/how-to-extend-django-user-model.html), but this [is my recommendation to use the email as a login](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/22/how-to-extend-django-user-model.html#abstractbaseuser)